# Searching and Mapping Frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe (df1) with values as follows :

[image: [v1,v2,v5]]
...

Basically, for each id all the corresponding values are grouped together in a list.

Now there is another dataframe (df2) in which there are multiple records for each id and variable combination (present in list column2) as follows :

[image]

NOTE :  column 2 has many more values for each ID, however we are only interested in the group of values present in df1 for each ID.

I want to search df2 based on the combination of values of id and its respective column2 value present in df1.

So that I could have the following result :

[image]

So far I have tried the following code to make df1 :

```
df1_mapping = df1.groupby(['column1']).apply(lambda x : x.values.tolist()[0][1:]).apply(set).apply(list).reset_index()
df1_mapping.columns = ['column1','all_mappings']
```

However, I am not able to efficiently search through df2 and I have to use brute force ( for loop ) to search through the dataframe. This is what I am using :

```
ID = []
VALUES = []
for i in range(len(df1_mapping)):
    id = df1_mapping.iloc[i,0]
    values = df1_mapping.iloc[i,1]
    data = df2[(df2['column1'] == id) & (df2['column2'].isin(values))].drop_duplicates()
    all_mappings = list(data['column3']) + list(data['column4']) + list(data['column5']) + list(data['column6'])

    ID.append(id)
    VALUES.append(all_mappings)
result = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(ID, VALUES)), columns = ['column1','all_secondary_mappings'])
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could guide me as how can I make the searching faster based on the above parameters. I don't want to use for loop, but I cannot figure out any other way and it's taking a lot of time to search the dataset for every combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by collecting all relevant columns from `df2` into a list, and grouping by `column1`.

```
# sample dfs
# please always provide samples as text, not image
# and make them so we can easily paste and test
# you can get it with `df.head(10).to_dict('split')
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'column1': ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'],
    'column2': [['v1', 'v2', 'v3'], ['v3', 'v4', 'v9'], ['v1', 'v2', 'v5']]
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[row.split() for row in [
        'id1 v2 x s b h',
        'id1 v2 y t c i',
        'id1 v3 z u d j',
        'id2 v3 p v e k',
        'id2 v4 q w f l',
        'id2 v9 r a g m',
        'id2 v5 a a a a' # should be filtered out
    ]],
    columns=[f'column{i}' for i in range(1, 7)]
)
```

The code

```
# first, get a master index for desired ids and variables
idx = df.explode('column2').set_index(['column1', 'column2']).index

# select rows from df2 that are in master index
df_temp = df2.set_index(['column1', 'column2'])
df_temp = df_temp[df_temp.index.isin(idx)]

# collect all columns in a list per row
df_temp = pd.Series(df_temp.values.tolist(), index=df_temp.index)

# groupby id and assign as new column in df
df = df.merge(
    df_temp.groupby('column1').sum().rename('all_values'),
        # as you can see, sum works on lists as well
    on='column1')
```

Output

```
  column1       column2                            all_values
0     id1  [v1, v2, v3]  [x, s, b, h, y, t, c, i, z, u, d, j]
1     id2  [v3, v4, v9]  [p, v, e, k, q, w, f, l, r, a, g, m]
```